# Почему тут нельзя использовать причастный оборот?

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика

Решая билеты ЕГЭ, допустил ошибку, связанную с этим предложением:

> Всё вокруг: лес, поле, журчащий ручей - было красиво той необыкновенно трогательной красотой, *которая так много говорит русскому сердцу*.

Почему "придаточную часть сложноподчинённого предложения нельзя заменить обособленным определением, выраженным причастным оборотом"? Разве нельзя оформить предложение так:

> Всё вокруг: лес, поле, журчащий ручей - было красиво той необыкновенно трогательной красотой, *так много говорящей русскому сердцу*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему "придаточную часть сложноподчинённого предложения нельзя
>   заменить обособленным определением, выраженным причастным оборотом"?

Потому что при такой замене указательное местоимение "той" в главном предложении становится лишним.

**ВОЗМОЖНА ЗАМЕНА** исходного сложноподчинённого предложения на простое предложение с причастным оборотом без указательного местоимения "той" перед определяемым существительным:

*Всё вокруг: лес, поле, журчащий ручей -- было красиво необыкновенно трогательной красотой,  так много говорящей русскому сердцу.*

Answer (score 2):

Согласна со Славой.

Нельзя заменить обособленным определением, выраженным причастным оборотом, придаточное определительное, если в главной части СПП имеется указательное местоимение (такой, такая, такое, такие, тот, та, то, те).
Например: Уже в ранних произведениях Достоевского обнаружились ТАКИЕ черты реализма, (которые выделили его из круга писателей натуральной школы). Грушницкий – один из ТЕХлюдей, (которые на все случаи жизни имеют готовые пышные фразы).

Вот здесь почитайте:   http://qwertyui11.blogspot.ru/2013/01/6.html

Только этого задания сейчас в ЕГЭ нет, это Вы старые КИМы решаете.

На ошибки осталось только зад.7. Вот ссылочка к нему, может, понадобится:
http://cdp.tti.sfedu.ru/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=85&Itemid=9

Answer (score 0):

Ответ исправлен

Во втором варианте (с причастным оборотом) лишним является указательное слово ТОЙ.

Теперь по поводу местоименной пары ТОТ-КОТОРЫЙ. Здесь, действительно, указательное слово (коррелят) возможно, так как это ВЫДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫЙ подтип определительного придаточного. 
Но есть еще РАСПРОСТРАНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ тип, где коррелят НЕВОЗМОЖЕН,например: У ворот мы увидели собаку, которая начала громко на нас  лаять.  Но нельзя сказать: У ворот мы увидели ту собаку, которая начала громко на нас лаять.

Поэтому  слово "который" всегда требует дополнительного внимания, не стоит утверждать, что коррелят возможен всегда.

Comment: Вера, почему в обоих вариантах? Первый верен, не знаю, где Вы нашли такое правило:"слово ТОЙ, его нельзя использовать в паре с союзным словом КОТОРЫЙ, имеющим распространительное значение". Тот, который..., та, которая...-норма построения СПП

Comment: Во втором варианте так нельзя сказать потому, что это соответствовало бы "началу лая до встречи с собакой", что невозможно по смыслу. Можно, правда, попытаться и необычный смысл приписать: мы встретили ту самую собаку, которая (как нам сказали хозяева) начала было лаять (им показалось, что громко), учуяв нас издалека, потом перестала - просто издалека мы её не видели и не слышали.

Comment: Ну да, все от ситуации зависит. Вот, например: "Итак, он решился идти в барский дом, который стоял от него в нескольких шагах". Но если рядом находилось бы два барских дома, то лучше идти в тот, который ближе.

Comment: P.S. Не заметил ещё одного возможного смысла: про собаку, о которой перед этим говорилось ("ту" собаку) - тогда здесь "ту" и "которая" взаимно не связаны, а смысл "уже знакомая собака при встрече залаяла".

Comment: Alex_ander, одними "собаками" здесь не обойдешься, проблема значительно масштабнее.  Но, как говорится, никогда не говори "никогда", можно и для этой собаки найти коррелят, например: "У ворот мы увидели ту собаку, которая начала громко на нас лаять (мы ее узнали по голосу среди других лающих на нас собак)".